# Is there a website to ask technical questions about the art of cinematography?

Tags: support

I've just created an account on this website. After having quickly looked at the main tags, [the on-topic page](https://movies.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) and some of the most upvoted questions, apparently, this website does not cover the technical aspects of the art of cinematography, for example, the different types of shots (e.g. long shot or close-ups) and their meaning, the art of screenwriting, the technical aspects of acting, etc.

Is there a SE website that covers or is entirely dedicated to such aspects? In other words, I am looking for a website for people **seriously** interested in the art of cinematography, in particular, film making or directing, acting, screenwriting, film and sound editing, etc. So, I am looking for a website where, for example, a person seriously interested in becoming a film director, an actor or a screenwriter could be helped.

I would like to note that I have some background in cinematography, so please do not tell me that this website is dedicated to cinematography or people seriously interested in it (unless I haven't found the type of questions I was looking for, which is also possible). This website seems to be dedicated to people who are, for example, curious about certain historical events. In fact, the most upvoted question is [How did they make cars fall apart in old movies?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/79161/77190). The second most upvoted question is [How do they film the mirror scenes in movies?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/2190/7719), which seems (a bit) dumb (without wanting to disrespect the asker) for someone who has some experience in cinematography (in particular, movie directing).

A related website is https://video.stackexchange.com, but it does not seem to focus on cinematography and it probably completely ignores all main aspects of it.

Comment: This website is *also* for people "seriously interested" in how specific cinematographic shots are *accomplished* and what they *express*, and I very much dare to tell you so. But yes, it approaches these topics more from the angle of consumers trying to analyse *existing* work, rather than people trying to *create their own* films, which would be more what you're looking for.

Answer (score 3):

**In a short answer, No.**

As you have already ascertained this is a site for enthusiasts and fans of movie content primarily - with some technical content, mostly so that interested viewers can understand how certain content is created.

There have been over time some people from the industry that have contributed here, but the community here isn't dominated by that group and as a result the content doesn't contain the more profoundly serious content that you crave.  Doesn't mean the questions are dumb, just being asked by people who don't consider themselves experts.

There isn't another SE site that fulfills your specific needs. Sorry.

Comment: But, in theory, could I ask questions about the technical aspects of film directing, acting, etc., here, or are you saying that this website is not in principle dedicated to these technical topics?

Comment: @nbro  In theory you could ask here, and you may get an answer - but it is not as certain.  You are very welcome to try.

Comment: @nbo - I would even go as far as to say I would encourage more industry content, I'm just wanting to set expectations.  Welcome.

Comment: Maybe we could create a proposal for cinematography on https://area51.stackexchange.com, but I am not sure how many people would commit to the website.

Comment: @nbro ... I'm inclined to agree with you that it might be slow to pick up commits, but you never know.  I proposed the Raspberry Pi site, and now it's a fully graduated site.